# Как в java отобразить время до окончания

Tags: java

У меня есть код:

```java
System.out.println("(" + ((timeUtil.getMS()+out-System.currentTimeMillis())/1000) % 60 + "s)");
```

Этот код подсчитывает оставшиеся секунды, так вот, он показывает целое число секунд `2, 22, 54`, а как к нему добавить ещё и одну миллисекунду? `(2.3, 22.7, 54.8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведите время к типу `double` и отформатируйте дробное число с помощью [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)), оставив только 1 знак после запятой:

```java
double diff = (double) (time - System.currentTimeMillis());
String output = String.format("(%.1fs)", diff / 1000 % 60);
System.out.println(output);
```

На выходе получим:

```
(54.8s)
```